# okta NetDocuments passing wrong credentials to ND?

Tags: okta

I just added `NetDocuments` app and am trying to log a user in. `NetDocuments` rejects the credentials with this message:

> Login error: 80131501 SAML request ID is invalid
>   Visit our support page for help.

and presents me with their login form, which works just fine.

`NetDocuments` has 2 fields on their login page: `Email` or `Username`. Our account with `NetDocuments` is setup to use the username field (using email field does not work).

I see there is no way to select that in the `Okta` setup though! So, is `Okta` passing my information to the username field? Or the email field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Under the general tab of your application in Okta just put the link NetDocuments provides you from their configuration page. It would be something like this: 'https://vault.netvoyage.com/neWeb2/docCent.aspx?whr=YourRepositoryID'

[Image of Okta config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6kqN.png)